# Swift 3 Delegate, Protocol -- TapGesture not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitapgesturerecognizer

I can't figure out why my tap gesture is not working.  The black cancel window show fine, but neither handleCancel() function is called when I tap on the black window.

```
import UIKit

protocol BlackCancelWindowDelegate {
    func handleCancel()
}

class BlackCancelWindow: NSObject {
    let blackView = UIView()
    var delegate: BlackCancelWindowDelegate?
    var frame: CGRect?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func showCancelWindow() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            blackView.frame = frame ?? window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            let tapToDismiss = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
            tapToDismiss.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(tapToDismiss)


            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {
                self.blackView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        print("BlackCancelWindow cancel")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

        delegate?.handleCancel()
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, BlackCancelWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func showCancelWindow(_ sender: Any) {
        let cancelWindow = BlackCancelWindow()
        cancelWindow.delegate = self
        cancelWindow.showCancelWindow()
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        print("Delegate cancel")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a button to my blackView and that button will not respond to a click either.  For some reason I feel like my blackView does not read any gestures.

Comment: Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` property to true

Comment: Tried that.  No dice.  I did find a solution though.  Will add below.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this works and my previous code doesn't, but the trick is to subclass UIView instead of NSObject.  Like this ...

```
import UIKit

protocol BlackCancelViewDelegate {
    func handleCancel()
}

class BlackCancelView: UIView {
    var delegate: BlackCancelViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    }

    convenience init() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.init(frame: window.frame)
        } else {
            self.init()
        }
    }

    func showCancelWindow() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            alpha = 0

            window.addSubview(self)
            let tapToDismiss = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
            addGestureRecognizer(tapToDismiss)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {
                self.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        print("BlackCancelView cancel")

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

        delegate?.handleCancel()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, BlackCancelViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func showCancelWindow(_ sender: Any) {
        let cancel = BlackCancelView()
        cancel.delegate = self
        cancel.showCancelWindow()
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        print("Delegate cancel")
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I did those init functions in the proper way.  Please let me know if there is a better way to do that.